# Relational Algebra Operator Tree

Tags: relation-algebra

**Context:** 
All customer pairs (C1,C2) such that C1 likes some pizza that C2 does not like.

**LikeDislike(cname, cname2):**

[image: LikeDislike(cname, cname2)]

**Question:** Find all customer pairs (C1,C2) such that C1 < C2 and they like exactly the same pizzas.

**Answer:**

[image: Answer]

I'm not sure about the right side of the operator tree. Why does the answer include LikeDislike? When they are asking about C1 & C2 liking exactly the same pizzas.

Comment: What are $\pi \sigma \rho?$  You question seems to end in the middle.  What comes after "Would be"?

Comment: I forgot to delete the "Would be", thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Relational Algebra--> π: Projection, σ: Selection, ρ: Renaming